# Script "tennis common opponent" in R

Tags: r, database, statistics

I'm follow this article about "common opponent in tennis", my goal is to script it in the most effecient way. Below you can find my code but is so slow. For calculate the result of 1 match my laptop spent 120seconds more or less, and I have a dataset of 150k of rows to calculate.

the article: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82518495.pdf

Need your help to clean and improve my code. Any suggestion is appreciate

tableA: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-ZKKnf0H4jafxCX96NLxu00nc

tableB: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-ZKKnf0H4javHgoPjzfCMXhg4

data_tennis_co: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-ZKKnf0H4jaJyNkYrr8muff8k

```
data_tennis_co = read.table("test_co.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", fill = TRUE)
A = read.table("tableA.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", fill = TRUE)
B = read.table("tableB.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", fill = TRUE)

#BASIC FUNCTIONS
G<-function(p){res<- p^4*(15-4*p-((10*p^2)/(1-2*p*(1-p))))}
d<- function(p,q) {res<- p*q*(1-(p*(1-q)+(1-p)*q))^-1}
TB <- function(p,q) {res <- foreach(i = seq_along(1:28), .combine = sum) %dopar% {tb<-A[i,1]*p^A[i,2]*(1-p)^A[i,3]*q^A[i,4]*(1-q)^A[i,5]*d(p,q)^A[i,6]}}
S <- function(p,q) {res <- foreach(i = seq_along(1:21), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {s<-B[i,1]*G(p)^B[i,2]*(1-G(p))^B[i,3]*G(q)^B[i,4]*(1-G(q))^B[i,5]*(G(p)*G(q)+(G(p)*(1-G(q))+(1-G(p))*G(q))*TB(p,q))^B[i,6]} sum(res)}
M3 <- function(p,q) {res <- S(p,q)^2*(1+2*(1-S(p,q)))}
DELTA_AB <- function(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC) {res <- (spwAC-(1-rpwAC))-(spwBC-(1-rpwBC))}
PR<- function(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC) {res <- (M3(0.6+DELTA_AB(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC),(1-0.6))+M3(0.6,(1-(0.6-DELTA_AB(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC)))))/2}

#COMMON OPPONENTS
MAL<-function(id1,id2){
prova<- subset(data_tennis_co, V3 == 1 & V4==2)
  previous<-subset(data_tennis_co, V2 < prova$V2)
  s1 <- subset(previous, V3 == 1 | V4==1)
  s2 <- subset(previous, V3 ==2 | V4==2)
  s1$opp <- ifelse(s1$V3==1, s1$V4, s1$V3)
  s2$opp <- ifelse(s2$V3==2, s2$V4, s2$V3)
  inn<- intersect(s1$opp,s2$opp)
  common1<-s1[s1$opp %in% inn,]
  common2<-s2[s2$opp %in% inn,]
  # fare media se id non unico
  COM <- merge(common1, common2,by=c("opp"))
  COM$OMALLEY <- unlist(mapply(PR, COM$V5.x, COM$V6.x, COM$V7.y, COM$V8.y))
  COM$OMALLEY[is.nan(COM$OMALLEY)] <- 0.5
  return(tryCatch(sum(COM$OMALLEY)/nrow(COM), error=function(e) NaN))
}

tic()
RESA<-MAL(1,2)
toc()
```

Comment: What are `tic()` and `toc()`?

Comment: I think this is one for [codereview.se], probably too broad for SO.

Comment: Meanwhile, have you tried using RStudio's built in profiler?

Comment: tic toc is a timing function.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tictoc/tictoc.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main bottleneck in the code is the use of parallel loops in TB and S, for operations that can be done faster using vectorized R functions.

```
G  <- function(p)    p^4*(15-4*p-((10*p^2)/(1-2*p*(1-p))))
d  <- function(p, q) p*q*(1-(p*(1-q)+(1-p)*q))^-1
TB <- function(p, q) sum(A[,1] * p^A[,2] * (1-p)^A[,3] *
                         q^A[,4] * (1-q)^A[,5] * d(p,q)^A[,6])
S  <- function(p, q) {
   Gp <- G(p)
   Gq <- G(q)
   sum(B[,1] * Gp^B[,2] * (1-Gp)^B[,3] * Gq^B[,4] * (1-Gq)^B[,5] *
      (Gp*Gq+(Gp*(1-Gq)+(1-Gp)*Gq)*TB(p,q))^B[,6])
}
M3 <- function(p, q) {
   s <- S(p,q)
   s^2*(1+2*(1-s))
}
DELTA_AB <- function(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC) (spwAC-(1-rpwAC)) -
                                              (spwBC-(1-rpwBC))
PR <- function(spwAC,rpwAC,spwBC,rpwBC) {
   D <- DELTA_AB(spwAC, rpwAC, spwBC, rpwBC)
  (M3(p = 0.6 + D, q = (1 - 0.6)) +
   M3(p = 0.6, q = 1 - (0.6 - D))) / 2
}
```

Solution here: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194301/tenis-common-opponents-r